# Ideas for Persistence Approach

Tags: asp.net, persistence

I'm looking for some ideas to best persist an object over multiple page requests without the use of session variables, cookies, context cache, view state or a session database.

I have a web form (ASPX) that will contain several user controls that will act as "pages", and these controls will be displayed in a one-at-a-time-manner:

```
<uc1:UserControl1 id="controlStep1" runat="server" visible="true" />
<uc2:UserControl2 id="controlStep2" runat="server" visible="false" />
<uc3:UserControl3 id="controlStep3" runat="server" visible="false" />
```

I have an object that I use to contain various parameters.  These parameters come into the application as query string values and this object lazy loads them.  For example:

```
public class Situation
{
    private string _jobId;
    private JobType _jobType;

    public string JobId
    {
        get
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhitespace(_jobId))
                return _jobId;

            _jobId = GetFromQueryString("jid");    
            return _jobId;
        }
    }

    public JobType JobType
    {
        get
        {
            if (_jobType != JobType.Default)
                return _jobType;

            _jobType = GetEnumFromQueryString("jtype", typeof(JobType));
            return _jobType;
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to persist this Situation object while the customer is in the web application, proceeding through a wizard-style interface as the user controls' visibilities are toggled.  At the moment, I'm creating an instance of the Situation object in an HttpModule during the customer's first request and storing it in HttpContext.Current.Items, but I'd like to use lazy loading so that the various Situation object properties are only loaded as needed.  However, if for example a property is accessed on controlStep1, I'd like to persist the state of the object so that if that same property is accessed on controlStep2, the getter doesn't have to go back to the query string to get the requested property's value.  I could serialize the object and deserialize in an HttpModule, but if a property is accessed and loaded, it wouldn't be remembered on the next request.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should explain what you have against the standard mechanisms for persisting state (Session, Cache,...).

Comment: View State => size management, 
Cookies => may be disabled by user, 
Session => policy - out of my hands :)

Comment: This questions seems related to "I want to build an ASP.NET website, but don't want to use ASP.NET". It's a bit silly.

Comment: If you're asking a question like this, you may want to rethink your architecture.

Comment: The ViewState is designed especially for this, and if you take good care of it, it will not grow out of control. Especially when you only persist that particular object in it.

Comment: @Steven, ViewState is good but you cannot manipulate it from an HttpModule.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  The current restrictions really are a little odd.  I'm all in favor of changing up the architecture; this discussion gives me a leg to stand on :)

Comment: @Bullines, why do you care about storing this object somewhere? I mean all that it does is retrieving query string parameters which shouldn't be a bottleneck if done on each request. Well you have a little cast over there for the enum but no deal-breaker.

Comment: @Darin.  I agree.  My example was very basic, but in reality, the Situation object contains more than QS values.  However, I think that I could serialize/deserialize those other types of properties on each request and leave the QS properties as they are.

Answer (score 1):

File system is sometimes a useful persistance mechanism.

Comment: I think this is about the only thing left (except uploading it to an FTP server or sending it by mail and retrieving it later ;-)).

Comment: @Steven, looool, I would opt for the mail solution.

Comment: @Steven, Thx for lightening the mood.  It makes me feel like the restriction craziness isn't just in my mind :)